# Sharepoint email format from workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, send-email

[image]

Sometimes email link is not correctly formatted when sending email from SharePoint designer workflow.

**Example:**

```
URL: http://shrepoint/SitePages/Information.aspx?ItemId=108&e=1 < http://shrepoint/SitePages/Information.aspx?ItemId=108&e=1 >
```

link is double.

why this is happened?

Comment: How are you adding URL in email? Can you add screenshot of Email body configuration in workflow?

Comment: I added screenshot. Please see this. Sometimes this problem occur. Not always. I get correct format but my client not getting correct format always